# Gradle disable javadoc except on deploy

Tags: gradle

I have enabled the javadoc for a project with

```
java {
  withJavadocJar()
}
```

The problem with this is that the javadoc is built everytime the library is built. In my case, this takes several minutes. Is there a good way to make the javadoc only run on `gradle deloy`?

Answer (score 0):

The following did the trick:

```
// Disables a task unless we're publishing something.
def disableUnlessPublishing(toDisable) {
  toDisable.enabled = false
  gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {
    gradle.taskGraph.allTasks
            .findAll { it.group == "publishing" }
            .any { toDisable.enabled = true }
  }
}
disableUnlessPublishing(tasks.javadocJar)
disableUnlessPublishing(tasks.javadoc)
disableUnlessPublishing(tasks.sourcesJar)
```